# Java Blackjack Game - wait for method

Tags: java, multithreading, blackjack

I'm trying to write an engine for a Black Jack game

(The UI is implemented by the console for now, but in the future it will be using JavaFX).

I have an`Engine` class and inside this class I have a method called `placeInitialBets()`.

I need that `Engine` will wait until all the players will place their bets, but for every player has a time limit.

Edit: The `Engine` class

```
public class Engine implements Runnable {

private final LinkedList<Player> players;
private final PriorityQueue<Event> events;
private final CardDeck deck;

public Engine(LinkedList<Player> players) {
    this.players = new LinkedList<>();
    this.events = new PriorityQueue<>();
    this.deck = new CardDeck();
    this.players.addAll(players);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    placeFirstBets();
}

private void placeFirstBets() {
    // Some code...
}
```

}

How can I implement this? Do I need to use a thread?

Comment: Yes you definitely need a `Thread`. But we'll answer no further unless u show us what you've done.

Comment: No, you don't need an explicit thread as a timer would serve the purpose as well. You set the game state to allow bets, but then at the completion of a timer set it so that it no longer allows bets. Using wait, which is not called on Threads but on Objects (and it darn well better be the right object) is a dangerous and low-level thing to do. You need to think ***Event-Driven Programming*** and ***State Dependent Behavior*** to code this best, not low-level coding hacks that will bite you in the arse.

Comment: Why not use a timer in a separate thread and force the betting to the next player when the timer event fires.

Comment: I'll explain it a bit different. Say i have a method `bet` in class `player`. Inside class `engine` i want to wait until the UI calls `bet` inside `player` class. How can implement this?